# How to disable the "named colours can only be accessed from an Asset Catalog in iOS 11.0 and later" warning?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11

I am getting the following warning

> You are targeting iOS 9.0, but named colours can only be accessed from
>   an Asset Catalog in iOS 11.0 and later

I am using named colours only in a situation where there is already a `if #available(iOS 11.0, *)`, so this warning is useless.
How can I disable this warning only? I don't want to get rid of all buildtime nor Asset Catalog warnings, just specifically this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to silence specific warnings in a Swift project in Xcode 9 anymore. You could only silence all asset catalogue related warnings but your question says that you do not want that.

I agree that this warning is annoying because there is nothing you can do to fix it (except not to use named colors or set your deployment target to iOS 11.0 )

So until you can set your deployment target to iOS 11.0 you should see this warning as a kind reminder from Xcode that you have to use the availability check when using named colors.

If this warning is a real problem because you told Xcode to treat all warnings as error your only option is to silence all asset catalog warnings in your target's Asset Catalog Compiler - Options